# Empty set as a singleton

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

So, it is obvious that the empty set is a subset of every set, such that **∀A:∅⊆A**.

Therefore, if the null set is an element of some set A, such that **A = {∅}**, is the empty set considered a singleton element of A?

Thank you.

Comment: Clearly distinguish between a "singleton set" and "element of set". What do you mean by a "singleton element" of a set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the set $\{\varnothing\}$ is a set whose only element is the empty set $\varnothing$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To clarify then, the cardinality of a set containing the empty set would indeed be 1?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: $|\{x\}| = 1$, $|\{Irma\}| = 1$, $\{\emptyset\}=1$.  $|$the set containing the set of all ice cream cones in the word$| = 1$ etc. as they are all sets that have just one single element.  Doesn't matter what the elements *is*-- just that there is one element.

Answer (score 0):

Yes $$\emptyset$$ is the one and only element of the set $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Divorce your mind from any thought that of an element being a set in its own right, from the role of the element as an element in another set.  If $x$ is the only element in $A$ then $x$ is a singleton element of $A$.  It doesn't matter *what* $x$ is and if $x$ just happens to be a set, its elements have nothing whatsoever to do with what kind of element $x$ is to $A$.

So $A=\{\emptyset\}$.  The $A$ has a single element.  That singleton element is $\emptyset$.

That's all that needs to be said.

.....

Um... I'm assuming you are taking "singleton" to mean the only element of  a set?